# How to convert Greensock's CustomEase functions to be usable in CreateJS's Tween system?

Tags: createjs, tween, easing, gsap, easing-functions

I'm currently working on a project that does not include GSAP (Greensock's JS Tweening library), but since it's super easy to create your own Custom Easing functions with it's visual editor - I was wondering if there is a way to break down the desired ease-function so that it can be reused in a CreateJS Tween?

Example:

```
var myEase = CustomEase.create("myCustomEase", [
    {s:0,cp:0.413,e:0.672},{s:0.672,cp:0.931,e:1.036},
    {s:1.036,cp:1.141,e:1.036},{s:1.036,cp:0.931,e:0.984},
    {s:0.984,cp:1.03699,e:1.004},{s:1.004,cp:0.971,e:0.988},
    {s:0.988,cp:1.00499,e:1}
]);
```

So that it turns it into something like:

```
var myEase = function(t, b, c, d) {
    //Some magic algorithm performed on the 7 bezier/control points above...
}
```

(*Here is what the graph would look like for this particular easing method.*)
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I took the time to port and optimize the original GSAP-based `CustomEase` class... but due to license restrictions / legal matters (*basically a grizzly bear that I do not want to poke with a stick...*), posting the ported code would violate it.

However, it's fair for my own use. Therefore, I believe it's only fair that I guide you and point you to the resources that made it possible.

The original code (not directly compatible with CreateJS) can be found here:
<s>https://github.com/art0rz/gsap-customease/blob/master/CustomEase.js</s> (*looks like the author was also asked to take down the repo on github - sorry if the rest of this post makes no sense at all!*)

Note that CreateJS's easing methods only takes a **"time ratio"** value (not `time, start, end, duration` like GSAP's easing method does). That time ratio is really all you need, given it goes from **0.0** (your start value) to **1.0** (your end value).

With a little bit of effort, you can discard those parameters from the `ease()` method and trim down the final returned expression.

**Optimizations:**

I took a few extra steps to optimize the above code.

1) In the constructor, you can store the `segments.length` value directly as `this.length` in a property of the CustomEase instance to cut down a bit on the amount of accessors / property lookups in the `ease()` method (where `qty` is set).

2) There's a few redundant calculations done per Segments that can be eliminated in the `ease()` method. For instance, the `s.cp - s.s` and `s.e - s.s` operations can be precalculated and stored in a couple of properties in each Segments (in its constructor).

3) Finally, I'm not sure why it was designed this way, but you can unwrap the `function() {...}();` that are returning the constructors for each classes. Perhaps it was used to trap the scope of some variables, but I don't see why it couldn't have wrapped the entire thing instead of encapsulating each one separately.

Need more info? Leave a comment!